# using jQuery options to animate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a jQuery plugin to do some animation but I want to pass the animation options in as a string like the following:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.animateBox = function (options) {
        options = $.extend({
            animation: "backgroundColor: '#0E4839', padding: '10px', color: '#ffffff', fontSize: '153.846%', margin: '0 0 1em 0'"
        }, options);

        return $(this).each(function () {
            var box = $(this);
            box.animate({ options.animation }, 'slow');
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Is this possible as the above is currently throwing an error complaining the dot in the `options.animation` should be a semi colon (as it is expecting something like `backgroundColor: '#0E4839'`)

Comment: make animation an object instead of string. then `box.animate(options.animation, 'slow');`

Comment: why do you want to pass it as a string and not as a object

Comment: @abhitalks ah, so simple! If you add that as an answer then I will accept

Comment: @Pete : thanks. added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the property as a string, but the jQuery animate expects an object. And you can't substitute a variable inside `{}` (an object literal).

So the easiest solution would be to make `animation` an object instead of string, so that it looks like this:

```
 options = $.extend({
   animation: {
     backgroundColor: '#0E4839', 
     padding: '10px', 
     color: '#ffffff', 
     fontSize: '153.846%', 
     margin: '0 0 1em 0'
   }
 }, options);
```

then change this:

```
box.animate({options.animation}, 'slow');
```

to this:

```
box.animate(options.animation, 'slow');
```